# Setzung des Kommas bei aufeinanderfolgenden Frageworten (wie wer was...)

Tags: punctuation, comma, interrogative

Ich glaube, ab und zu keine Kommata zwischen Frageworten, beispielsweise

> wer wie
>   wie wo
>   wer wie was
>   ...,

gesehen zu haben. Ich könnte mir etwa gut vorstellen, dass

> Die Polizei weiß schon, wer wie warum das Geld geklaut hat.

richtig ist. (Ist es so?)

Frage: Ist eine Kommasetzung möglich, obligatorisch oder verboten? Kann man die Frageworte auch so verwenden

> **Warum wie** hast du das gemacht?

oder so

> **Warum** und **wie** hast du das gemacht?
>   **Warum, wie** hast du das gemacht?

Comment: Die Rechtschreibung geht der Frage nach, wie einzelne (!) Wörter richtig geschrieben werden. Die Rechtschreibung kümmert sich um nichts, was außerhalb eines Wortes sonst noch vorhanden ist. Bei der Rechtschreibung geht es also nur um die Frage: »Welche Buchstaben müssen in welcher Reihenfolge aneinander gefügt werden, damit ein korrektes Wort entsteht?«. Wenn es um das Zusammenspiel mehrerer Wörter geht, oder darum, welche Zeichen man zwischen Wörter setzt, geht es nicht mehr um Rechtschreibung, sondern um Grammatik. Ich habe deine Frage entsprechend korrigiert.

Comment: Und den Satz, der mit Etwa beginnt, hast Du akzeptiert?

Comment: @userunknown: Das ist mir eine Frage wert: http://german.stackexchange.com/q/34093/1487

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Man kann einige Beispiele konstruieren, die anscheinend mehrere Fragewörter miteinander verbinden:

> Ich weiss, wer was getan hat.

Nur ist das *wer* in diesem Fall kein Fragewort (es handelt sich ja um keine Frage), sondern ein *Relativpronomen*, denn es leitet einen Relativsatz ein.
*was* ist in diesem Fall ebenfalls kein Fragepronomen, denn es wird immer noch nichts gefragt - sondern ein *Indefinitpronomen* und meint so viel wie "etwas".

In meinem Beispiel gibt es ein Komma, das zur Einleitung des Relativsatzes gesetzt werden **muss**.

Mehr als zwei solche "Frageworte" (es sind keine) in einem Satz zu verwenden, ergibt meiner Meinung nach keinen rechten Sinn - Dein Beispiel

> Die Polizei weiß schon, wer wie warum das Geld geklaut hat.

scheint mir kein korrekter Satz zu sein. Trennt man die Indefinitpronomen *wie* und *warum* durch ein "und", wird der Satz akzeptabel.

> Die Polizei weiß schon, wer wie und warum das Geld geklaut hat.

Die Frage nach der Kommasetzung stellt sich also gar nicht.

Und

> wer, wie, was, wieso, weshalb, warum?

geht einem nur so leicht von der Zunge, weil es jahrzehntelang der "Slogan" der "Sesamstraße" war.

Comment: Füge ein weiteres Wörtchen ein und du hast eine Aufzählung, die durch ein Komma getrennt ist. "Die Polizei weiß schon, wer wie, wo und warum das Geld geklaut hat." — Aber abgesehen davon, stimme ich deiner Antwort zu.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5nZRKEN4wb4

Comment: @Em1: Ich hab's nicht verstanden. Wer, wie, wo, warum was geklaut hat?

Answer (score 3):

Zu diesem Thema gibt es einen Beitrag im [Blog von Dr. Bopp](https://blog.canoonet.eu/2014/08/13/was-wie-wann-und-wo-und-die-kommas/). In dem dort diskutierten Beispiel kommt noch ein viertes, mit *und* angefügtes Fragewort vor - für Deine Frage also entsprechend zu

> Die Polizei weiß schon, wer wie, wo und warum das Geld geklaut hat.

Die Antwort (angewandt auf Deine Frage) stellt dar, dass die Fragewörter *wie, wo und warum* wie *aufgezählte* Adverbialbestimungen funktionieren, bezogen auf den Satz "Wer hat das Geld geklaut". Entsprechend gelten die Kommaregeln für Aufzählungen, während *wer* das Subjekt des Satzes darstellt und somit nicht vom Rest des Satzes abgetrennt wird. Formal spricht nichts dagegen, auch die verkürzte Form so zu behandeln, also

> Die Polizei weiß schon, wer wie, warum das Geld geklaut hat.

Allerdings wird eine Aufzählung aus zwei Elementen meist mit *und* verbunden, weshalb diese Variante etwas fremd wirken mag. Interessant finde ich deshalb, dass Dr. Bopp auf zwei Alternativen hinweist. Zum einen darauf, dass man die Fragewörter als gleichwertig empfinden kann und er deshalb auch ein Komma nach "wer" akzeptieren würde, auch wenn die syntaktische Analyse das nicht hergibt. Zum anderen darauf, dass insbesondere in der Variante ohne *und* die Fragewörter eben auch als Platzhalter gesehen werden können in einem Satz, den man "ausgefüllt" auch nicht mit Kommas schreiben würde, etwa so:

> Die Polizei weiß schon, wer mit List aus Habgier das Geld geklaut hat.

Aus diesem Blickwinkel gesehen, wäre auch Deine ursprüngliche Annahme richtig:

> Die Polizei weiß schon, wer wie warum das Geld geklaut hat.

Auf Deine Anschlussfrage lässt sich das aber nicht übertragen. Hier handelt es sich auf jeden Fall um eine Aufzählung, bei der Du die Fragewörter mit Komma trennen oder mit *und* verbinden musst.