# »Etwa« am Beginn eines Satzes

Tags: word-order, adverb

In [einer anderen Frage](https://german.stackexchange.com/revisions/34074/2) schrieb jemand sinngemäß diese Sätze:

> 1. Ich glaube, dieses und jenes schon gesehen zu haben. **Etwa könnte ich mir gut vorstellen**, dass ein bestimmtes Beispiel richtig ist.

Aufgrund eines Kommentars wurde das [wie folgt](https://german.stackexchange.com/revisions/34074/3) umgeschrieben:

> 2. Ich glaube, dieses und jenes schon gesehen zu haben. **Ich könnte mir etwa gut vorstellen**, dass ein bestimmtes Beispiel richtig ist.

Dass die zweite Version korrekt ist, steht außer Zweifel. Ich frage mich aber, ob die erste überhaupt falsch war. Ich glaube nämlich, dass sie ebenfalls grammatisch völlig korrekt ist. Denn hier wird das Adverb »etwa« als Synonym von »beispielsweise« verwendet, und mit diesem Wort am Beginn des Satzes wird, wie ich glaube, wohl niemand ein Problem haben:

> 1. Ich glaube, dieses und jenes schon gesehen zu haben. **Beispielsweise könnte ich mir gut vorstellen**, dass ein bestimmtes Beispiel richtig ist.

Das kann man natürlich auch in der Version 2 machen, aber die steht ohnehin außer Streit:

> 2. Ich glaube, dieses und jenes schon gesehen zu haben. **Ich könnte mir beispielsweise gut vorstellen**, dass ein bestimmtes Beispiel richtig ist.

Meine Frage:

Ist »**Etwa könnte ich mir gut vorstellen, ...**« grammatisch richtig oder falsch? Muss man diesen Satz korrigieren, oder kann man ihn, so wie er ist, stehen lassen?

Comment: *etwa* ist in deinen Beispielen ein Partikel, kein Adverb (also ein "Füllsel") - Partikel dürfen im Deutschen fast überall stehen - Ich sehe also in deinen Sätzen nichts Falsches. Andererseits fehlt mir an manchen Stellen ein "So", um die Bindung zum vorangesetzten Satz herzustellen, also "Ich glaube, das habe ich schon einmal gehört. *So* könnte ich mir etwa gut vorstellen,..."

Comment: @tofro Ich habe meine Antwort etwas verlängert: Die Frage ist, wie die Satzstellung bei einem Partikel am Satzanfang ist: "Partikel-Verb-Rest" oder "Partikel-Irgendwas-Verb-Rest"?

Comment: Habe meine Antwort komplett geändert...

Comment: @tofro: Wenn ich das Wort A in einem Satz durch das Wort B ersetzen kann, ohne das sich dadurch die Bedeutung des Satzes ändert, und wenn B ein Adverb ist, wie kann dann A etwas anderes als ein Adverb sein? (Die Partikel ist übrigens weiblich.)

Comment: Ich glaube nicht, dass "etwa" hier mit "beispielsweise" gleichzusetzen ist - Das ist der Hauptgrund, warum ich meine, dass es sich hier um ein**e** Partikel handelt. Duden hält die zwei Verwendungen auseinander, indem er sagt, dass die Partikelverwendung die *Möglichkeit* verstärkend ausdrückt. Sicher bin ich mir dabei ehrlich gesagt aber nicht. Die Übergänge hier sind wohl fliessend.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Kurz und knackig: Es ist natürlich korrekt, dass *etwa* hier ein Adverb ist. Und an einem Satz, der mit dem Adverb *etwa* beginnt, ist grammatisch nichts auszusetzen.

Sprich, das hier ist korrekt:

> Ich glaube, dieses und jenes schon gesehen zu haben. (So) Etwa könnte ich mir gut vorstellen, dass ein bestimmtes Beispiel richtig ist.

---

Man findet auch eine ganz Reihe an Beispielen im Internet. Meistens jedoch mit einem Komma oder ggf. mit einem Gedankenstrich abgetrennt und weniger mit einem Punkt. Da die Suche etwas einfacher nach *so etwa* ist, hier ein entsprechendes Beispiel:

> Edwards hatte auch mit anderen Filmen Erfolg - so etwa 1979 mit der romantischen Komödie «10» mit Bo Derek und Dudley Moore. <sup>[QUELLE](http://www.appenzellerzeitung.ch/nachrichten/kultur/Regisseur-Blake-Edwards-gestorben;art41,1658696)</sup>

Answer (score 3):

Obwohl 'etwa' hier ungefähr dieselbe Bedeutung vermitteln wie 'zum Beispiel', ist es im *Vorfeld* nicht gut verwendbar und klingt unidiomatisch.

Warum? Das ist schwer zu sagen. (Spekulation: Üblicherweise wird 'etwa' nachgestellt und ganz unbetont verwendet. Das ist ein im Deutschen sehr seltenes Muster, und vielleicht verträgt es sich nicht gut mit der prosodisch prominenten Rolle im Vorfeld.)

Dieses Phänomen ist aber auf diese spezifische Bedeutung von 'etwa' beschränkt. Das 'etwa' mit der Bedeutung von 'ungefähr' kann dagegen problemlos als Satzanfang verwendet werden:

> Etwa zwanzig Zeugen waren bei dem Vorfall anwesend.